# How much data is loaded onto the client after a Meteor.subscribe?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Inside of `Meteor.publish`'s callback function we return cursors. So does it mean that when we do a subscribe on the client, only a minimum amount of data is transferred to the client?

It's only when we do something on the client like `cursor.fetch` or `cursor.forEach` that the collection data is actually being pushed onto the client?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything that is defined in your `Meteor.publish` will be sent down to the client:

e.g if you have

```
Meteor.publish("rooms", function() {
    return Rooms.find();
});
```

The entire result of the query `Rooms.find()` is sent down to the client. The `.fetch()` only fetches all the data from the cursor which helps stop looping through all of the unnecessary data (in memory). The cursor's fetch/forEach won't influence the subscription and data availed from the server.

To control what comes down to the client you need to explicitly tell the subscription/publish what to publish to the client. A good example on how to do this is the Chat & Rooms example at the meteor docs under [subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe)

Comment: To clarify, so right after you do a subscribe on the client, the entire `Rooms` collection is being loaded onto the client's minimongo?